# monodevelop System.DllNotFoundException calling a function in a C++ library

Tags: c#, c++, linux, dll, monodevelop

I have a C++ library libmylib32.so compiled for Linux Ubuntu 32bit.

The library is in usr/local/lib and I confirmed it is working in a C++ program.

In file /etc/mono/config I added

```
<dllmap dll="mylib32.dll" target="/usr/local/lib/libmylib32.so"/>
```

and I have also tried with

```
<dllmap dll="mylib32.dll" target="/usr/local/lib/libmylib32.so" os="!windows"/>
```

I wrote a C# program with monodevelop to call the C++ function:

```
short libhndl( const char *, unsigned short, long, unsigned short * );
```

First I wrote a class where the interface of the function is declared:

```
public class MyClass
{

[global::System.Runtime.InteropServices.DllImport("mylib32.dll", EntryPoint="libhndl", CharSet = CharSet.Ansi)]
public static extern short libhndl( [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPStr)] string ip, ushort port,int timeout, out ushort libHndl);

}
```

The main program calls the function libhndl:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;


public class main_program
{
// ...
 ret = MyClass.libhndl(ip_address, tcp_port, tcp_timeout, out m_libHndl);
//...
}
```

If I debug the program, when the fucntion is called I get the exception:

```
System.DllNotFoundException: /usr/local/lib/libmylib32.so
 at (wrapper managed-to-native) MyClass:libhndl (string,uint16,int,uint16&)
 at main_program.function () [0x00056] in
 /home/f90100027/workspace/Ex_mono/Ex_mono/main_program.cs:306 
 at System.Threading.Thread.StartInternal () [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0
```

The library appears to find the library because the exception shows the complete library path.

Can anybody explain where the problem could be, please?

Thank you in advance for your help.

Following the advice to set the env var MONO_LOG_LEVEL=debug the debugger returns

```
Mono: DllImport error loading library 'libmylib32.so': '/usr/local/lib/libmylib32.so: undefined symbol: _ZTVN10__cxxabiv117__class_type_infoE'.
```

The command nm /usr/local/lib/libmylib32.so returns

```
...
000144c0 T libhndl
...
0013ee30 V _ZTV9SocketMgr 
         U _ZTVN10__cxxabiv117__class_type_infoE
...
```

Comment: 1) Set the env var  `MONO_LOG_LEVEL=debug` to get a **very detailed** dump of exactly where Mono is probing to find that shared library and what is really failing. 2) Skip the dllmap and use LD_LIBRARY_PATH to tell Mono where to probe for it, i.e.  `export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/local/lib:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH These should get more info to fix help you fix it or more info for us to assist.

Comment: I get  an undefined symbol which I cannot understand.  Mono: DllImport error loading library 'libmylib32.so': '/usr/local/lib/libmylib32.so: undefined symbol: _ZTVN10__cxxabiv117__class_type_infoE'.

Comment: Appear to be c++ name managing, those C++ routines need to be tagged as `extern "C"`, I see your other commit that you do not have the source... You could create another C++ based library to wrap those calls with the `extern "C"`. See http://www.mono-project.com/docs/advanced/pinvoke/ for more info about the ABI calling interface required

Answer (score 0):

I'm not totally sure how mono works with C++ code, but I'd imagine your problem is related to C++ name mangling. Try wrapping your code in a `extern C` block.

Try

```
extern "C" {
short libhndl( const char *, unsigned short, long, unsigned short * );
}
```

instead.

Comment: Unfortunately I do not have the source files of the library